# OutputStream.write - Possible with ONLY byte? Or int casted to byte?

Tags: android

Currently, I know OutputStream.write only accept `byte` or `byte[]`

But I'm looking to do something like:

```
int[] pd = new int [255];
pd[0] = (byte) 255;

OutputStream.write(pd);
```

But apparently, as stated, `.write` only accepts `byte` or `byte[]`.

How do I cast it to a byte so that I can send in the array itself as a whole?
Thanks

Comment: why would you declare an int[] only to put bytes in it?

Comment: @njzk2 because the data that I can compile is only applicable to int though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop the array and cast the current element to a byte and send it:

```
for(int b : pd) {
     outputStream.write((byte) b);
}
```

Comment: Yes you loop element by element, cast it, and send it

Comment: So it is the same thing as sending a byte in? Mind just explaining abit about the `int b: pd` ? I don't quite get it for that part. The colon and such. Is it like pd is being assigned to int b?

Comment: It is a foreach loop. b will hold the current value. The loop will run for all the values of the array

Comment: So for example. pd[0] = 255; pd[1] = 254;
For first loop b = 255? and it will cast to byte and send? then next loop is b = 254 , cast and send?